# Require in JS is not able to read string from object, but can read the same string individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object array, techstack

```
let techStack = [
      {
        name: "C",
        image: "../Utils/C.png",
        rating: 4,
      },
      {
        name: "Java",
        image: "../Utils/Java.png",
        rating: 3.5,
      },
      {
        name: "Python",
        image: "../Utils/Python.png",
        rating: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "React Js",
        image: "../Utils/React.png",
        rating: 3.5,
      },
      {
        name: "Bootstrap",
        image: "../Utils/Bootstrap.svg",
        rating: 3.5,
      },
      {
        name: "Node.Js",
        image: "../Utils/Node.png",
        rating: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "Flask",
        image: "../Utils/Flask.png",
        rating: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "MySql",
        image: "../Utils/SQL.png",
        rating: 4,
      },
    ]
```

And I am trying to render image's source (`<img src={} />`) with `image` value from each object, like this:

`<img src = {require(tech.image)} alt={tech.name} />`

But while rendering, I get an error saying `Cannot find module '../Utils/C.png'`. But when I use the same string separately (like `src={require("../Utils/C.png")}`) the image is being rendered without any error. Why is this happening and how can I solve it.

I have used Material UI components.

Here is the JSX element

```
{techStack.map((tech, id) => (
  <Grid key={id} item xs={6} md={3} my={4}>
    <div>
        <Tooltip title={tech.name}>
          <img
            src={require(tech.image)}
            alt={tech.name}
            style={{ marginBottom: "2%" }}
            width={sizeBreak ? "50px" : "100px"}/>
          </Tooltip>
          <div>
            <Rating
              readOnly
              value={tech.rating}
              precision={0.5}/>
          </div>
    </div>
  </Grid>
))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the resulting artifact is not the same as your sources. webpack(or your other bundler) doesn't handle pictures correctly as it can't statically understand what should be bundled and how from the code above. To fix that, I would propose to put `require` call in the array instead of in the component

```
let techStack = [
      {
        name: "C",
        image: require("../Utils/C.png"),
        rating: 4,
      },
....
src={tech.image}
```

this way webpack would bundle C.png correctly

Comment: What if I am reading the data from a MySQL? The previos array has hardcoded values, but since the data is being fetched from MySQL, how can I solve the issue?

Comment: I would say the right way would be to either store pictures on the backend and provide url to that picture. Or you could add an assets folder to your frontend with all of the pictures, then you would be able to load image for the corresponding item when provided

Answer (score 0):

The difference is first one is compiled as a variable not a path to the image but the second one is a path that the compiler will check.
I suggest an easy way. import images first and use this `src={tech.image}`

Comment: Still not working man. But src accepts string right, and the type of value for the key `image` is a string, right. So that should work, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not all the fact, the point is when the bundler is working on your code see this `require("")` because the value will pass to the line at runtime so the images didn't import. the path of images depends on your asset management in project

Comment: Hey...thank you for the response, really appretiate that, but I got my solution. It's add `require` in the obj array itself.